# remove table row with html5 data attribute in column

Tags: jquery

I have a button that is in every row of a table. That button uses the html5 data attribute. That attribute comes from the server.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>...</td>
<td><button class="deletebutton" data-delete="<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>">Delete Camera</button></td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

I try to process it with that attribute in jquery:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".deletebutton", function() {
    var camerahash = jQuery(this).data("delete");
    jQuery.ajax({
       url: "index.php?option=com_cameras&task=deletecamera&camera_hash="+ camerahash +"&format=raw",
       success: function(){
            jQuery("selector here to identify tr of table using camerahash").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Since I have `camerahash` (data attribute) already for other things it would be nice to use that to identify the table row even though but it is part of a column. But I'm not really sure what selector to use here to identify the table row for the corresponding column?

It doesn't have to be this way, but I thought this would be clean-ish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a reference to `this` in a variable (`$this`), and then use `closest()` to find which table row it belongs to in your callback.

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".deletebutton", function() {
    var camerahash = jQuery(this).data("delete");
    var $this = $(this);
    jQuery.ajax({
       url: "index.php?option=com_cameras&task=deletecamera&camera_hash="+ camerahash +"&format=raw",
       success: function(){
            $this.closest('tr').remove();
        }
    });
});
```